# Cannot instantiate a class that extends java.util.List

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a class that extends list so that when I use it in multiple programs I can just type `GeneticAlgorithm<ObjectName> test = new GeneticAlgorithm<ObjectName>();` I cant figure out how to create the class in its own file. It gives an error that says "Cannot instantiate the type `GeneticAlgorithm<Bird>`".

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class GeneticAlgorithm<E> implements List<E> {

   public GeneticAlgorithm() {

   }
}
```

and in main

```
public class GeneticsMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GeneticAlgorithm<Bird> test = new GeneticAlgorithm<Bird>();
    }
}
```

I was able to figure it out. i had the wrong idea at first. Thank you for you help thought.

Comment: Are you asking how to develop genetic algorithms (in which case this question is far too broad)?  Or are you asking how to put a class in its own `.java` file?

Comment: im trying to create a class that uses another class as the creature that evolves. i can do the rest of the genetic algorithm math

Comment: So it seems you could just put your two classes in the same package; which means that there will be two `.java` files in the same directory.  Then either one would be able to use the other, without any `import` statements.  Which part is causing you difficulty?

Comment: Don't declare a class abstract if you want to be able instantiate it... Also consider extending `AbstractList` instead of implementing `List`. BTW: Are you sure implementing/extending `List` is the right thing here? A genetic algorithm doesn't sound like it IS-A list.

Comment: Your problem is that you've declared `GeneticAlgorithm` as `abstract`, which means that you can't instantiate it directly.  If `GeneticAlgorithm` has to be abstract, then you'd need a further (non-abstract) subclass to be able to make instances.  But if you remove the `abstract` keyword, you'll have to supply implementations of the methods in the `List` interface.  A better idea might be to extend one of the standard implementations of `List` (such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`) instead of trying to make your own `List` implementation from scratch.